# How to use a function of own class in for_each method?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, function-object

Assume I have this class (inherited from std::Vector, it's just an example)

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class C : public vector<T> {

    // I don't want to use static keyword
    void transformation(T i) {
        i *= 100;
    }

    public:   
    void method() {
        for_each(this->begin(), this->end(), transformation);
    }
};

int main() {
    C<double> c;
    for (int i=-3; i<4; ++i) {
        c.push_back(i);
    }

    c.method();
}
```

How do I call for_each using class method inside class itself? I know I can use static keyword, but what is there any other way how to use a function object without using static?

I get this error message while compiling:

> for_each.cc:21:55: error: cannot convert
>   ‘C::transformation’ from type ‘void (C::)(double)’
>   to type ‘void (C::*)(double)’    for_each(this->begin(),
>   this->end(), transformation);

I think I need to add `.*` or `->*` somewhere but I can't find out where and why.

Comment: Well, I think I've found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006685/call-a-member-function-using-for-each

Comment: What about the lambda solution?
for_each(this->begin(), this->end(),  [this](T& ob) {transformation(ob);});

Comment: You probably want `void transformation(T& i);`, not `void transformation (T i);`.

Comment: For what it's worth, you typically shouldn't inherit from any of the standard containers. They don't have virtual destructors, so any polymorphic deletes will do partial destructions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++11 *bind* solution:

```
std::for_each(this->begin(), this->end(),
      std::bind(&C::transformation, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

C++11 *lambda* solution:

```
std::for_each(this->begin(), this->end(),
      [this] (T& i) { transformation(i); });
```

C++14 *generic lambda* solution:

```
std::for_each(this->begin(), this->end(),
      [this] (auto&& i) { transformation(std::forward<decltype(i)>(i)); });
```

C++98 *bind1st+mem_fun* solution:

```
std::for_each(this->begin(), this->end(),
      std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&C::transformation), this));
```

---

<sub>**Note:** `this->begin()` and `this->end()` calls are qualified with `this->` only because in the OP's code they are member functions of a templated base class. As such, those names are primirarily searched in a global namespace. Any other occurrence of `this` is mandatory.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

For starters, *don't* inherit from the standard containers, they are not designed to be inherited (no virtual destructors etc.).

Secondly, and regarding your problem, it's because a pointer to a member function is not the same as a pointer to a function. The reason is that member function has a hidden first parameter which becomes the `this` pointer in the function. The simplest way to solve it is to make the function `static`.

Another solution is to use the [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) function that came with C++11:

```
for_each(this->begin(), this->end(),
    std::bind(&C::transformation, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

If you *don't* have C++11 (even though you tagged your question as such), then you probably could get something working with [`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) or [`std::bind1st`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12).

Comment: Inheriting from standard containers is fine, as long as you don't use polymorphism. Polymorphism is not the only reason to use inheritance, and there can be useful applications of inheriting from standard containers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `this` pointer:

```
public:   
void method() 
{
    for_each(this->begin(), this->end(), bind(&C::transformation, this, placeholders::_1));
}
```